# Operator overload requires parenthesis

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have overloaded both `&` and `*`.  If I do this:

`hgh=(xxx&yy)*vprod1;`

It works as expected.

If I do this:

`hgh=xxx&yy*vprod1;`

I get a compiler error `Invalid operands to binary expression.`

How does the compiler read this: `hgh=xxx&yy*vprod1;` -- Wouldn't it move from left to right, just as in the above example, with parenthesis? If the parenthesis were located in a different part of the expression, I can understand how there could be differences in how the compiler read it, but why would that apply here?

It should be worth noting that the return value of both overloads is identical, and returns the same type as `xx` and `yy` are in this calculation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`*` has higher precedence than `&`, so it's applied first. Your expression is basically `xxx & (yy * vprod1);`

Comment: But if the operators are declared as described in the question, I still don't understand why there is an error message about invalid operands.

Comment: @jogojapan the error could be referring to `operator =`? I agree it's weird, something else is probably going on there...

Comment: Possible. It may not matter any more (the answer has been accepted), but I feel there is a piece missing from the question.

Comment: I haver overloaded versions of these operators so the signature in the question adds confusion here so I will remove it. Luchian's answer indeed solved the issue. @jogojapan